# Moving (std::move) out class members correctly according to the C++ standard

Tags: c++, stl, standards, move

If i have a class containing a member which i want to move out like a unique_ptr or unique_lock ... is is correct according to the standard just to move it out just like this:

```
#include<memory>
class C 
{
    public:
    C(): _data(std::make_unique<int>(42)){ }
    C(const C&) = delete;
    C(C&&) = delete;
    C& operator=(const C&) = delete;
    C& operator=(C&&) = delete;

    [[nodiscard]] std::unique_ptr<int> give_data() {
        return std::move(_data);  // correct?
    }

    private:
    std::unique_ptr<int> _data;
};

int main()
{
    C obj;
    auto data = obj.give_data();
    return *data;
}
```

according to STL all STL class objects are in a valid but undefined state after move; meaning the class invariant holds. Is this true in general? How can this be improved?

Comment: Most standard C++ library objects are left in a "valid but unspecified state" after moving (suitable for destruction, or being assigned to; member functions with no preconditions are also okay to invoke).  Some, like `std::unique_ptr`, are left in a *specified* state (in its case, it'll hold a `nullptr` pointer). Your own *user defined types* can be left in whatever state you decide is most appropriate (I usually do the "valid but unspecified state" as my own policy, following the standard C++ library's lead).

Comment: The built-in move capability of the library code will be disabled by deleting the moves. Why are you deleting them? However, it's perfectly ok to steal so long as you don't use the object later.

Comment: Qt has examples of this pattern. By Qt convention, such functions are named starting with `take`. E.g. [`QList::takeAt`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlist.html#takeAt). "Take" in this context generally means "remove something from its current owner (on whom the method is called) and transfer ownership to the caller".

Comment: `give_data` is not a move constructor or a move assignment operator; the standard doesn't place any requirements on how an arbitrary member function of your class should behave. So the right question to ask is not "what the standard requires", but "what makes sense for the design of your class". Is it meaningful for an instance of `C` to have `_data == null`? That's what `obj` would have after `obj.give_data()`

Answer (score 0):

I got the input that std::move (which is a cast) is already seen as code smell (e.G Jason Turner). So like in the copy /swap ideom swap can be used to "move" the data, which is possible for every swappable type:

```
#include<memory>
class C 
{
    public:
    C(): _data(std::make_unique<int>(42)){ }
    C(const C&) = delete;
    C(C&&) = delete;
    C& operator=(const C&) = delete;
    C& operator=(C&&) = delete;

    [[nodiscard]] std::unique_ptr<int> give_data() {
        std::unique_ptr<int> result{};
        swap(result, _data);  // Using swap to move the data
        return result;
    }

    private:
    std::unique_ptr<int> _data;
};

int main()
{
    C obj;
    auto data = obj.give_data();
    return *data;
}
```

Comment: About `std::move` is a code smell: Only if you move a local variable in a `return` statement (and types match). Your original code does not move a local variable, but a member; `std::move` is very approriate for this case. Your solution in this answer does 3 moves at least instead of just 1 move in the original.

Comment: I don't see three moves even in older standards. Only one is allowed in C++17 and above meaning the result move construction. GCC removed this move already on unoptimized builds. msvc is quite bad om optimizing this stuff:
https://compiler-explorer.com/z/jdv4n6WWd

Comment: There are 3 moves in `swap`.

Comment: You are right swap() is most probably resolved to std::swap() where the implementation  swap over a temporary object. The benefit of this implementation: It leaves the member in a programatically defined state no matter what datatype it is. I think this pays out for me.